# Want to get total row count in footer of spring batch without customizing writer(Delegate Pattern)

Tags: spring-batch, footer, rowcount

This is my footer class:--

```
public class SummaryFooterCallback extends StepExecutionListenerSupport implements FlatFileFooterCallback{

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("footer - number of items written: " + stepExecution.getWriteCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }


}
```

This is my xml:--

`<bean id="writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" ref="outputResource" />
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator" />
        </property>
        <property name="headerCallback" ref="headerCopier" />
        <property name="footerCallback" ref="footerCallback" />
    </bean>
<bean id="footerCallback" class="org.springframework.batch.sample.support.SummaryFooterCallback"/>`

Failing at stepExecution.getWriteCount() with nullpointer Exception.

No, I haven't registered callback as a listener in the step. I am new to Java and Spring Batch, referring to your book Pro Spring Batch but not able to get the solution of the assigned task.

Comment: How do you create/access the callback?

Comment: < bean id="writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
  <property name="resource" ref="outputResource" />
  <property name="lineAggregator">
   <bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator" />
  </property>
  <property name="headerCallback" ref="headerCopier" />
  <property name="footerCallback" ref="footerCallback" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="footerCallback" class="org.springframework.batch.sample.support.SummaryFooterCallback" />

Comment: 1.  Please update your original question with the XML you pasted in your comment so we can read it properly.  2.  Have you registered your callback as a listener in the step?

Comment: Comment updated.

Comment: Thanks issue resolved, I registered my callback as a listener. Thanks Michael Minella.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the writer in [scope step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/3.0.x/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope). Here you have a java based config that worked for me.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemStreamWriter<Entity> writer(FlatFileFooterCallback footerCallback) {
    FlatFileItemWriter<Entity> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<Entity>();
    ...
    writer.setFooterCallback(footerCallback);
    ...
    return writer;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
private FlatFileFooterCallback getFooterCallback(@Value("#{stepExecution}") final StepExecution context) {
    return new FlatFileFooterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
            writer.append("count: ").append(String.valueOf(context.getWriteCount()));
        }
    };
}
```