# how to write record count to xml file in spring batch

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am reading a multiple flatfiles using FlatFileItemReader and writing to  multiple xml files using StaxEventItemWriter .I want to add the record count at the end xml file(total no of records).

sample output xml file:

```
<test>
  <fileid>1</fileid>
   <filename>1</filename>
    <consumers>
     <consumer></consumer>
     <consumer></consumer>
     <consumer></consumer>
     <consumer></consumer>
     <consumer></consumer>
    </consumers>
  <recordCount>5</recordCount> ---total no of consumers.
 </test>
```

Appropriate any help on this.

Comment: Please show us your configuration or code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542978/want-to-get-total-row-count-in-footer-of-spring-batch-without-customizing-writer

Comment: Thanks a lot Luca Basso Ricci it worked.

Comment: HI Luca Basso Ricci, Reocrd count is not working with  multiResourceWriter. not able to print record count on individual file